# AlamofireImage cache?

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, alamofireimage

I use `AlamofireImage` in conjunction with `PromiseKit` and `Alamofire`. I use promises to chain the download of x number of images since I want to do this synchronically. I can't seem to understand if `ImageDownloader()` caches automatically or if I have to add the image explicitly to the cache? The only examples I've seen so far are not using the `ImageDownloader` so I have a real hard time finding an answer to this.

If not - how do I add it the cache? I've tried using:

```
self.imageDownloader.imageCache?.addImage(image, withIdentifier: imageUrl)
```

But all it does is increase my memory usage for all eternity(i.e. adding the same image to the cache over and over)

Answer (score 0):

I think that defining an AutoPurgingImageCache() and then using it while caching process need to solve your memory usage problem.

```
let photoCache = AutoPurgingImageCache(
    memoryCapacity: 100 * 1024 * 1024,
    preferredMemoryUsageAfterPurge: 60 * 1024 * 1024
)
```

You can change **memoryCapacity**, **preferredMemoryUsageAfterPurge** represent MB. To add any image in your cache, you can use like that:

```
photoCache.addImage(scaledImage, withIdentifier: urlString)
```

Also you can check [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36331740/swift-how-to-save-memory-using-alamofireimage-imageshack) for more details and [AlamofireImage GitHub](https://github.com/Alamofire/AlamofireImage) page.

Comment: There's a small syntax error there. To add the image to the cache, you'd call `.add` instead of `.addImage`

Answer (score 0):

I was also using the same approach you did here. But according to the API reference the image should be added to cache automatically:

`Each downloaded image is cached in the underlying NSURLCache as well as the in-memory image cache that supports image filters.`

https://alamofire.github.io/AlamofireImage/Classes/ImageDownloader.html